# Aggregate nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents, and I'm trying to aggregate all documents with companyId = xxx and return one array with all the statuses.

So it will look like this:

```
[
{
    "status": "created",
    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
},
{
    "status": "completed",
    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
},
{
    "status": "created",
    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
},
{
    "status": "completed",
    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
},
{
    "status": "created",
    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
},
{
    "status": "completed",
    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
},
{
    "status": "created",
    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
},
{
    "status": "completed",
    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
}
```

]

The document look like this:

```
[
{
    "companyId": "xxx",
    "position": "",
    "section": "",
    "comment": "",
    "items": [
        {
            "any": "111",
            "name": "some name",
            "description": "some description",
            "version": "3",
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "created",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
                },
                {
                    "status": "completed",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "any": "222",
            "name": "some name",
            "description": "some description",
            "version": "3",
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "created",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
                },
                {
                    "status": "completed",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "companyId": "xxx",
    "position": "",
    "section": "",
    "comment": "",
    "items": [
        {
            "any": "111",
            "name": "some name",
            "description": "some description",
            "version": "3",
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "created",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
                },
                {
                    "status": "completed",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "any": "222",
            "name": "some name",
            "description": "some description",
            "version": "3",
            "status": [
                {
                    "status": "created",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T10:59:59.200Z"
                },
                {
                    "status": "completed",
                    "date": "2019-03-16T11:00:37.750Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Any suggestion, how to implement this?

Then I want to loop over the array (in code) and count how many items in status created, and completed. maybe it could be done with the query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { companyId: "xxx" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items.status"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$items.status"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$status",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Double [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) will return single status per document and then you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote each status to root level of your document.

Additionally you can add [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage to count documents by `status`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @mickl answer, you can add `$project` pipeline to get the result as a flat list of status and count.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { companyId: "xxx" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items.status"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$items.status"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$status",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "status":"$_id", 
            "count":1,
            _id:0
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of documents on which you are executing the above query is too much then you should avoid using **$unwind** in the initial stage of aggregation pipeline.
Either you should use **$project** after **$match** to reduce the selection of fields or you can use below query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      companyId: "xxx"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$items.status",
          initialValue: [

          ],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```